# How to automatically enable paredit mode on all clojure, closurescript and elisp buffers automatically?

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, paredit

I want to enable paredit-mode on all clojure, cljs and elisp buffers by default, which is probably going to happen through the .spacemacs file. This is what I have so far in the user-config function of my .spacemacs:

```
;; paredit autoload
  (autoload 'enable-paredit-mode "paredit" "Turn on pseudo-structural editing of Lisp code." t)
  (add-hook 'clojure-mode #'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'clojurescript-mode #'enable-paredit-mode)
```

But it doesn't really work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I use emacs and not spacemacs (yet) but I thing you should just had "-hook" at the end of the mode to make it works:
`(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)` and `(add-hook 'clojurescript-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)`. Does it work?

Comment: No it didn't work.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Please don't ask the same question here and also on  [Emacs SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58741/how-to-automatically-enable-paredit-mode-on-all-clojure-clojurescript-and-elisp) (and a *second time* on [Emacs SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58742/how-to-automatically-enable-paredit-mode-on-all-clojure-closurescript-and-elisp).) Choose one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

In the [paredit-mode wiki](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Paredit-mode) one can see it should be:

```
;; paredit autoload
  (autoload 'enable-paredit-mode "paredit" "Turn on pseudo-structural editing of Lisp code." t)
  (add-hook 'clojure-mode 'enable-paredit-mode)
  (add-hook 'clojurescript-mode 'enable-paredit-mode)
```

So not `#'` but instead of that `'`.

Comment: and this? `(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook (lambda () (paredit-mode +1)))`

Comment: ah true, because you use `cider` for clojure, I guess.

Comment: then try `(add-hook 'clojure-mode (lambda () (paredit-mode 1))` and `(add-hook 'clojure-script-mode (lambda () (paredit-mode 1))`. If that also doesn't work I would delete all clojure relevant packages in the `elpa` folder and reinstall them again.

Comment: are you using `use-package` for your package configs? Actually you have to add `(paredit-mode 1)` into the `:config` there for `clojure-mode` or `clojure-script-mode`.