# Emacs, clojure, cider-jack-in

Tags: emacs, clojure

Originally when I started to use emacs with clojure, and cider-jack-in, when I opened Parenthesis, eamcs automatically closed it.
also, if I was on the first character of this code

```
(dotimes [n 3]
  (println "hi" n))
```

and press CTRL-k, emacs cut both lines.
Somehow I lost these features. I tried to reopen emacs and run emacs-jack-in again, but it is not working like that anymore. How could I turn it on again?
thanks

Comment: Sounds like paredit was enabled before and now it's not, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031589/how-to-automatically-enable-paredit-mode-on-all-clojure-closurescript-and-elisp

Comment: hello @schaueho, I think that should be it, but if I type M-x paredit-mode and it says "Paredit mode is enabled in current buffer" but still doesn't close parenthesis :(

Comment: C-k (kill) might be what you were thinking of. C-y after C-k "pastes" the killed stuff back in.  If you summon mode help with C-h m, you can see that Paredit bound C-k to its own version of the kill feature.